# Sublime Text 3 - Different colour scheme for each workspace

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to specify a different colour scheme for each workspace in Sublime Text so that I can easily identify which one I'm working on? In my situation, I have a single project that branches into two duplicate workspaces; one for a client and one for in-house development. In other words, each workspace is an instance of the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save your workspace as a separate project.

Open up your `.sublime-project` file. (*Top menu* -> *Project* -> *Edit project*)

It will look similar to this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/home/user/some_path/project"
        }
    ]
}
```

Simply add the color scheme setting:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/home/user/some_path/project"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "color_scheme": "Packages/Toxin Color Scheme/Toxin.tmTheme"
    }
}
```

You can get the color scheme path by switching it as you normally do (e.g. from top menu) and opening your `User Preferences`.